# Use hasMany Relation with Model Attribute

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following model:

```
class User extends Model {

    public function addresses() {
        return $this->hasMany('Addresses');
    }

    public function billAddress() {
        return $this->addresses()->where('id','=', $this->idBill);
    }
}
```

The following query will result in an empty collection.

```
\App\User::has('billAddress')->get();
```

However, any instance of a user has a `billAddress`.

Is it simply not possible to use `$this->attribute` in  a hasMany relation? Or is there some other way how to achieve this?

Comment: Try to not load the relation, so `public function billAddress() {
        return $this->hasMany('Addresses')->where('id','=', $this->idBill);
    }`

Comment: You can use this package: https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships

Answer (score 1):

`\App\User::has('billAddress')->get();` results in an empty collection, because `\App\User` is not one particular user, but the actual *User Model*.

Assuming that you have an existing User in your database and that `$idBill` is defined in the User Model, you can get the 'billAdresses' relation like this:

```
$user = User::find(1); // just an example, but it has to be a User Model
$billAddresses = $user->billAddress->get(); // the result your are looking for

foreach ($billAdresses as $billAddress) {
    // your code
}
```